# Controller input is coming from the left or right controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

I am receiving touchpad input values from both VR controllers. However, I would like to distinguish between the left and right controller values. Specifically, when I touch the left controller's touchpad, I want to save those values in the "Vector2 moveL," and when I touch the right controller's touchpad, I want to store the values in "Vector2 moveR."

Current code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Valve.VR;

public class CursorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensativity = 0.1f;
    public float maxSpeed = 1.0f;

    public SteamVR_Action_Vector2 moveValue;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveL = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 moveR = Vector2.zero;

        // Check if the controller input is coming from the left or right controller
         moveL.x = moveValue.axis.x;
         moveL.y = moveValue.axis.y;
        
       
         moveR.x = moveValue.axis.x;
         moveR.y = moveValue.axis.y;
        

        Debug.Log("Left Controller: " + moveL);
        Debug.Log("Right Controller: " + moveR);
    }
}
```

I want to differenciate left and right controller touchpad values.

Comment: Can't you configure two separate actions for this?